# Terraform, conditionally execute some lines of code in template file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform, is there any way to conditionally execute some lines of code in template file? For example:

I have a test.sh.tpl file defined as below called from main.tf

#!/bin/bash
echo ${test_key} > /opt/test_key.properties

In the above value to "test_key" is assigned from variable

Now I want to execute the above code only if ${test_key} value is not empty. I tried this, but not working even the value exists

{ if ${test_key} != "" }

echo ${test_key} > /opt/test_key.properties

{ endif }

Answer (score 7):

probably because you are missing %

```
%{ if ${test_key} != "" }

echo ${test_key} > /opt/test_key.properties

%{ endif }
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html

Comment: Tried that, Call to function "templatefile" failed:./test.sh.tpl:3,7-8: Invalid character; This character is not used within the language., and 2 other diagnostic(s).

Comment: if you are populating through tpl file you can follow the example below.  because it quite easy to add if condition within shell script

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file

Comment: It's also invalid to say `if `${test_key}` ... `${` is for switching from literal mode to interpolation mode, but we're already in `if` mode here so can (and must) just say `%{ if test_key != "" }`

Comment: @MartinAtkins is right! ${test_key} inside `if` doesn't work. But otherwise the answer worked.